# Load mask for Jasny bootstrap plugin

Tags: jasny-bootstrap

I am using Jasny Bootstrap for input masking in my application got stuck at one point.

I have a text box where i want to apply masking(only enter numbers not less then 1 and not greater then 1111) but in my case if I can type less then 4 digits its not accepted. Any help ?

```
<input class="form-control" id="txtEIN" type="text" data-mask="9999" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any characters after "?" are optional

```
<input class="form-control" id="txtEIN" type="text" data-mask="9?999" />
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/ndhwgjsk/)

Comment: and if I want to mask input field with currency?